# Solve: $2\log_{3}(x)-\log_{3}(x+6)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

just getting going with logarithms, having trouble with this question.

$$2\log_{3}(x)-\log_{3}(x+6)=1$$
$$\log_{3}x^2-\log_{3}(x+6)=1$$

Stuck at this point: What do I do next?
$$\log_{3}\bigg({\dfrac{x^2}{x+6}}\bigg)=1$$

Edit: Got it!

$$\dfrac{x^2}{x+6}=3^1$$
$$\dfrac{x^2}{x+6}=3$$
$${x^2}=3(x+6)$$
$$x^2=3x+18$$
$$x^2-3x-18=0$$
$$(x-6)(x+3)=0$$

$x=6 $ and cannot equal $\ne3$ as $2\log_{3}(-3) < 0$.

Comment: Hint: the exponentiation is the inverse of log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good so far. Now use the property that

$$\log_3 a =  b \iff a = 3^b$$

This leads to

$$\frac{x^2}{x + 6} = 3$$

Rearranging, this is a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use exponents. If $\log_xy=z$, then $y=z^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Proceeding from T. Bongers' concise solution: $$ x^2 = 3 \cdot (x + 6) \implies x^2 - 3x - 18 = 0. $$Now, we can try to factor this. We notice that it can be factored as follows: $$ (x+3)(x-6) = 0 \implies x \in \{ -3, 6 \}. $$Since $x=-3$ is extraneous, $x=6$ is the only solution.

Comment: Are you positive? I thought -3 is extraneous in $2\log_{3}(-3)$ makes $ x < 0$

Comment: @nitrous2 You're right, thanks. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

To get $x$ out of logarithm, you raise the base (3) with the logarithm (as log and exponent are inverses)

$\log_{3}(\frac{x^{2}}{x+6}) = 1$

$3^{\log_{3}(\frac{x^{2}}{x+6})} = 3^{1}$

$\frac{x^{2}}{x+6} = 3$

then solve the quadratic to get $x$ value